# Disabling all input elements except some in a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable almost all input elements in a form using jquery, but I need some input elements to be enabled. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#document :input[name!='tloEnable']).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

This works great on the elements I have with the same name 'tloEnable'. However there are a few other elements that have different name attributes (filename, notifyUsers, notifyTeam). How can I include them too while disabling the remaining input elements?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#document :input[name!='tloEnable], [name!='filename'], [name!='notifyUsers'], [name!='notifyTeam']).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: Use a common class on the elements and make your life easier.

Comment: You could add a `disabled` class to the input elements which should be disabled.

Comment: use common class for the elements that you want to enable.

Comment: If, for some reason, you still don't want to use a class, you can do it [**this way**](http://jsfiddle.net/gsp6y9uh/), but it's ugly and probably harder to maintain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`.not() function`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and pass a selector; matched elements will be excluded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input").not("[name=tloEnable], [name=filename], [name=notifyUsers]")
        .prop("disabled", true);
});
```

The [`:not() selector`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) works the same way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input:not([name=tloEnable], [name=filename], [name=notifyUsers])")
        .prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Give the inputs you wish to disable a class such as `disabled-inputs`. Then simply:

**Jquery 1.6:**

```
$(".disabled-inputs").prop('disabled', true);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below:**

```
$(".disabled-inputs").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Salman A's solution is the one I would probably go with** (assuming you can't just give the fields a classname) but you could also consider using [jQuery's `filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to only select elements that match your criteria.

Here we're just checking that `name` does not exist in our list of `fieldsNotToBeDisabled` but you could easily extend it to test for anything else.

```js
var fieldsNotToBeDisabled = new Array("tloEnable", "filename", "notifyUsers", "notifyTeam");

$("form input").filter(function(index){
    return fieldsNotToBeDisabled.indexOf($(this).attr("name"))<0;
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

```css
input {border:1px solid green; }
input:disabled { border-color: red; background:#eee;}
```

```html
<form>
    <input name="tloEnable" />
    <input name="filename" />
    <input name="notifyUsers" />
    <input name="notifyTeam" />
    <input name="testa" />
    <input name="testb" />
    <input name="testc" />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').not('#company_email_1, #company_email_2, #company_email_3, #company_email_4').attr('disabled', true)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.